# zk framework : zul file, pure java or hybrid for better performance

Tags: java, zk, zul

zk framework is very flexible for web developers. But flexibility also brings some issues. I wonder which method is the best for performance (memory, time etc.)

1) .zul files, that consists scripts like :

```
<vbox>
        Auto-complete Combobox:
        <combobox id="combo" autodrop="true" mold="rounded"/>
        <hbox>
            <checkbox checked="true"
                onCheck="combo.autodrop = self.checked"
                label="auto drop popup when typing" />
            <checkbox checked="true"
                onCheck="combo.buttonVisible = self.checked" label="button visible" />          
        </hbox>
        <checkbox label="Use rounded combobox" checked="true"
            onCheck='combo.mold=self.checked? "rounded": "default"'/>
    </vbox>
    <zscript>
    String[] _dict = { 
        "abacus", "accuracy", "acuity", "adage", "afar", "after", "apple",
        "bible", "bird", "bingle", "blog"
...
```

2) pure java like

```
public class TestRenderer {

    ListModelList model = new ListModelList();
    private AnnotateDataBinder binder;

    @AfterCompose
    public void afterCompose(@ContextParam(ContextType.VIEW) Component view) {
        binder = new AnnotateDataBinder(view);
     List persons = new ArrayList();    
     model.add(new Person("David", "Coverdale"));
...
```

3) hybrid zk

```
<window apply="com.synnex.wms.outbound.so.IndexViewCtrl">
    <style>
        .z-row-cnt .z-label {
            white-space:nowrap;
        }
    </style>
    <grid model="${model}" rowRenderer="${renderer }" height="300px" width="800px">
        <custom-attributes org.zkoss.zul.grid.rod="true" />
        <custom-attributes org.zkoss.zul.grid.initRodSize="20" />
        <columns>
            <column forEach="${headers}" label="${each}" width="80px"/>
        </columns>

    </grid>


</window>
```

are they differ when using with different technologies like spring? is java to html parsing faster than zul to html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also notice that the evaluation of EL expressions is very fast, so EL
>   can be used in a production system. On the other hand, zscript is
>   suggested to use only in prototyping or quick-fix.
>   
> [Link](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/UI_Composing/ZUML/Scripts_in_ZUML#Distinguish_zscript_from_EL)

So do not use 1) 
2) can be faster, slower or as fast as 3) depends on your impl.,
but to be faster may takes much time and so 2) isn't a really good idea.
3) is usually the best, cos a zul file is much more readeable then java code
and GUI logic and GUI structure are not (that much) mixed up.

To choose between MVC and MVVM read [this](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Small_Talks/2011/December/MVVM_in_ZK6%3ain_Contrast_to_MVC).
If you think it makes sense to mix them, there should
be no problem with the framework.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to use MVVM Architecture it will boost up your development as i worked on ZK MVC as well as MVVM i will prefer MVVM Architecture you can take maximum benefits of Component based programming with this approach otherwise if your project is complex and your are using MVC Architecture you are increasing your headache but some time we have to use MVC approach also but from my understanding best approach will be MVVM

Answer (score 1):

The guys from the ZK framework actually recommend separating server-side from client-side.
They say don´t mix Java code with ZUL files and I can talk from my own experiences that it is true because of the performance issues when mixing them up.

Keep the zscript to a minimum, keep it out if not actually necessary, und handle your coding on the server-side.

It actually is pretty clear in there Getting Started Tutorial http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Getting_Started/Tutorial